# Socket? python -m SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python, sockets

**Problem:** to get the command working [here.](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/71/serve-current-directory-tree-at-httphostname8000) My domain is http://cs.edu.com/user/share_dir, but I cannot get the command working by typing it to a browser:

```
http://cs.edu.com/user/share_dir:8000
```

**Question:** How can I get the command working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your URL is incorrect. The port number should be specified after the domain name:

http://cs.edu.com:8000/

Some other things you should keep in mind:

1. If this is a shared host, port 8000 might already be in use by someone else
2. The host might not be accessible from 'outside' of the network, due to firewall restrictions on non-standard ports
3. The system you see internally could map to a different system outside, so the domain/hostname could be different from what you expect.

Comment: Are you sure? Many other users have a subdomain under the domain. If the domain is relly your suggestion, my admin has probably blocked such commands. Is there some way to test the command otherwise?

Comment: Yes, the format of the URL you specified, http://cs.edu.com/user/share_dir, is a way to get the web server serving files from your home directory. The Python method you want to use bypasses the normal web server and creates a brand new one listening directly on the host where you run it.

Comment: Is it possible to create a socket to the place where I wanted it: http://cs.edu.com/user/share_dir:8000

Comment: No, unfortunately not. The /user part is handled by your host's default web server and you are starting a new one on port 8000.